# BlobStore Redirects being ignored by ServletModule wired servlets

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect, blobstore

After the blobstore handles the upload request of a file it redirects to the url it is given, in this case "/upload". If I configure the UploadServlet url in web.xml like this:

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.....servlet.UploadServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/upload</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It works. If I use Guice to wire the servlet:

```
serve("/upload").with(UploadServlet.class);
```

I get the error:

```
Problem accessing /upload. Reason:NOT_FOUND
```

It seems as though the com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule does not handle redirects. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with the same issue myself today. This solved my problem and may be related:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-java/oqfvEmZGrdw

> In dev mode, the blobstore service uses 
>   RequestDispatcher.forward() rather than an HTTP request:

```
    <filter-mapping> 
            <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name> 
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
            <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
    </filter-mapping> 

    <filter-mapping> 
            <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name> 
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
            <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> 
    </filter-mapping>
```

Of course, may be too late for you but for others it might help :-)